# Nice implementations of Console.WriteTable(DataTable), Console.WriteList(LIst)

Tags: c#, console-application

Are there any implementations to display nicely table or list data in c# console app like say in PowerShell? 
Upd. Maybe third side or any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there aren't out of the box. You will need to implement it yourself depending on the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your saying you want to make a nice organized list instead of all uneven and messy, if so youd want to use `PadRight()` or `PadLeft()` for lists of data.